# Perl Sorting Multiple Keys Hash

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, key

I have a hash

```
%grades{$subject}{$student}=$score
```

I am trying to extract top 30 scores for each subject with students from the hash which requires sorting, but I'm not sure how to sort the multiple key hash.

So far I have this, but this gives me every single one of the scores instead of the top 30 that I need for each subject. Also, is there a faster way to perform the query since I have almost 200K students.

```
foreach my $subject(sort keys %grades) {
    foreach my $student(keys %{ $grades{$subject} }) {
        print "$subject, $student: $grades{$subject}{$student}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an example hash and example output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sorts the top 2 scores for each subject (just for illustrative purposes).  You should change `0 .. 1` to `0 .. 29` for the top 30:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %grades = (
    math => {bill=>55, joe=>66, mike=>77},
    hist => {bill=>72, joe=>33, mike=>99},
    read => {bill=>95, joe=>24, mike=>22},
);

for my $subject (sort keys %grades) {
    my %gr = %{ $grades{$subject} };
    for my $student ((reverse sort { $gr{$a} <=> $gr{$b} } keys %gr)[0 .. 1]) {
        print "$subject $student $gr{$student}\n";
    }
}

__END__

hist mike 99
hist bill 72
math mike 77
math joe 66
read bill 95
read joe 24
```

Refer to [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES) and [How do I sort a hash (optionally by value instead of key)?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-%28optionally-by-value-instead-of-key%29?)

Answer (score -3):

Count them.

```
$count++;
last if $count > 30;
```

Comment: But the values aren't sorted, how will count work in this case? And I'm not sure how to arrange the values in order.